# Saving XML via PowerShell always inserts a comment with inconsistent line endings

Tags: xml, powershell

The project I am working on has multiple `web.<env>.config` files. I found that the variables in an element like `<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" />` are replaced only in the main web.config file but they need to be updated in all .config files. My solution to this problem was to write a PowerShell script that takes the value of `%LAUNCHER_PATH%` and `%LAUNCHER_ARGS%` after the project has been built and update the other .config files.

The script I wrote works as intended but when I open the updated file in Visual Studios after I've updated it and the application complains that the file has inconsistent line endings when no such warning is presented prior to running the script. I have confirmed in Notepad++ that there are certain lines that only contain a `LF` and not `CR LF` and they relate to this comment that keeps getting inserted into my file.

```
  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->
```

I have found that no matter what I do, this comment keeps getting inserted into my file; even if I only load and immediately save the file.

### Script

```
# Updates web.{env}.config files with the correct processPath and arguments
# that are populated in web.config during the publish process 

$folder = "."
$nodeXpath = "configuration/system.webServer/aspNetCore"

if (Test-Path "$folder\web.config") 
{
    $originalNode = Select-Xml -Path "$folder\web.config" -XPath $nodeXpath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
    $processPath = Select-Xml -XPath "@processPath" -Xml $originalNode
    $arguments = Select-Xml -XPath "@arguments" -Xml $originalNode

    Get-ChildItem $folder -Filter web.*.config |
    Foreach-Object {
        # Using .NET XmlDocument
        $xml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
        $xml.PreserveWhitespace = $true
        $xml.Load($_)
        #$node = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath $nodeXpath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
        #$node.SetAttribute("processPath", $processPath)
        #$node.SetAttribute("arguments", $arguments)
        $xml.Save((Resolve-Path $_))
    }
}
```

### XML Being Read and Saved Into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
    <security>
      <authorization>
        <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
        <add accessType="Allow" users="blah" />
        <add accessType="Allow" roles="blahblah" />
        <add accessType="Allow" roles="blahblahblah" />
      </authorization>
      <authentication>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The comment will be inserted right above `<system.webServer>`.

Is there a way to force the save action to not insert the comment? If that is not possible, is there a way to correct the comment such that it does not have inconsistent line endings compared to the rest of the file?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the issue. I save your XML to C:\Temp\web.config, and C:\Temp\web1.config. I remove the values for processPath and arguments from web1.config. I updated `$folder='C:\Temp'`, `Get-ChildItem $folder -filter web1.config`, `$xml.load($_.fullname)`, and `$xml.save($_.fullname)`, and uncommented the 3 lines for `$node`. I ran the script, verified that the 2 attributes were correctly set, and did not see the comment you see, or any malformed line ends in Notepad++. Are you checking Notepad++ after running the script but before opening the project in VS?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you should instead handle the part you *do* have control over, which is writing the file itself, to ensure that its line-breaks match what Visual Studio is adding. It seems like the comment is being added with `LF` only while the rest of your file is using `CRLF`.

You can control the output by creating your own `XmlWriter` with its own settings:

```
$folder = "."
$nodeXpath = "configuration/system.webServer/aspNetCore"

if (Test-Path "$folder\web.config") 
{
    $originalNode = Select-Xml -Path "$folder\web.config" -XPath $nodeXpath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
    $processPath = Select-Xml -XPath "@processPath" -Xml $originalNode
    $arguments = Select-Xml -XPath "@arguments" -Xml $originalNode

    $settings = [System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings]::new()
    $settings.NewLineChars = "`n"

    Get-ChildItem $folder -Filter web.*.config |
    Foreach-Object {
        # Using .NET XmlDocument
        $xml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
        $xml.PreserveWhitespace = $true
        $xml.Load($_)
        #$node = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -XPath $nodeXpath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node
        #$node.SetAttribute("processPath", $processPath)
        #$node.SetAttribute("arguments", $arguments)

        $writer = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create((Resolve-Path $_), $settings)
        try {
            $xml.Save($writer)
        } finally {
            $writer.Close()
        }
    }
}
```